# monkey patch node module

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron

I'm trying to monkey patch [this node module](https://github.com/johnvmt/node-desktop-screenshot) in [electron](https://electronjs.org/) application. I want to change the `capture` method input arguments.

My code so far looks like this:

```
if (process.platform == "darwin") {
      let refSCapt = screenshot.capture;
      console.log("Outside");
      screenshot.capture = function(output: string, callback: any) {
        console.log("Inside");
        // Override output path of a temp .png file
        let tempOutput = output.split("/")[-1];
        refSCapt(this.screenshotsPath + tempOutput, callback);
      };
    }
```

The problem is that the patch is not reflecting and the original method is called as if nothing would've change. The `Outside` get's logged but the `Inside` is never called.

So how can I monkey patch this module method?

Comment: The question lacks http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unclear what `capture` method is and where it came from. The package doesn't seem to contain this method. Unless proven otherwise, it's always preferable to wrap and extend, not patch.

Comment: @estus: https://github.com/johnvmt/node-desktop-screenshot/blob/master/capture/darwin.js#L36.

Comment: It's a function that is never exported. You cannot wrap or patch it. Fork the package and tailor it to your needs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> So how can I monkey patch this module method?

What you have would work fine ... but *only* if your code runs before it is used elsewhere. For reliable patching I recommend https://github.com/ds300/patch-package which patches modules on install.