# override export function from node module (js)

Tags: javascript, function, overriding

I'm trying to override function from node module package that i use in my project
but give me error of

`TypeError: Cannot set property myFunc of #<Object> which has only a getter`

the strange thing is i already did this override in old project year ago and there wasnt any error

example for how i do it: (import the function from the node module path(its exported from the node module) , and override it)

```
import {myFunc} from '../../utils';

myFunc = function () {
...
...
}
```

i tried search in google for this error but the results are for property override not functions

Comment: I think I understand, but let me confirm... you want to make sure that any other file that also does `import {myFunc} from '../../utils';` will **also** get the changed version of `myFunc`.  is that right?  Because what you're attempting would only affect the function that is stored in the variable `myFunc` it wouldn't change what the module `../../utils` has for its function.

Comment: yep, that what i trying to.. and its worked for me in old project myFunc is the function define name

anyway its keep give me error in the console of type error..

the purpose is when other files inside this pacakge calling myfunc from utils its will redirect them to my override function

Comment: You are attempting to do [_monkey patching_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49142668/monkey-patch-node-module) and I think people use things like [`patch-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) or [`rewire`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) for this.

Comment: i see now that in my old project there was plugin "terser-webpack-plugin", maybe its what let me override with out error